# NSDataDetector with NSTextCheckingTypeLink detects URL and PhoneNumbers!

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am trying to get an URL from a simple NSString sentence. For that I use NSDataDetector in the following code:

```
NSString *string = @"This is a sample of a http://abc.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA sentence with a URL within it and a number 097843."; 
NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil]; 
NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {

  if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
    NSString *matchingString = [match description];
    NSLog(@"found URL: %@", matchingString);
  }
}
```

The result is that it finds the URL and the number. The number is detected as a phone-Number:

```
found URL: http://abc.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA
found URL: tel:097843
```

Is that a bug? Could anyone tell me how to get the URL without that telephone number?

Comment: Okay, got it!

To prevent getting a phone number I am checking the first seven letters like:

    NSString *httpString = [aString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,7)];
    if ([httpString isEqualToString:@"http://"]) {
        // my coding   
    }

Comment: It is really odd since there is another NSTextCheckingType called `NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber` specifically for checking phone numbers.

Answer (score 11):

`NSDataDetector` necessarily detects telephone numbers as links because on the phone, you can tap them as if they were a link in order to initiate a phone call (or tap and hold to initiate a text message, etc).  I believe that the current locale (ie, `NSLocale`) is what determines whether a string of numbers looks like a phone number or not.  For example, in the United States, it would take at least seven digits to be recognized as a phone number, since numbers in the US are of the general form: `\d{3}-\d{4}`.

As for recognizing a telephone link versus another link, it's not a good idea to check for `http://` at the beginning of the URL.  A simple example suffices: what if it's an `https://` link?  Then your code breaks.

The better way to check this would be like this:

```
NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
  NSURL *url = [match URL];
  if ([[url scheme] isEqual:@"tel"]) {
    NSLog(@"found telephone url: %@", url);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"found regular url: %@", url);
  }
}
```

Comment: The behavior of NSTextCheckingTypeLink detecting phone number is really odd. It only detects 5~6 digit numbers but not real phone numbers like 888-6666. Do you know why? Or is it a known bug?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me ... this behavior is gone in iOS7