# How to identify if string is a phone number, mail address or a web address?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have some data coming from server in form of string. The string might contain a phone number or mailing address or a web address apart from other information. Is there some way I can identify which part is  phone number or mail address or web address?

In Android there is some API which can actually tell this. I was wondering if there is any such support in iPhone too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this thread. This thread will explain how to get URL and PhoneNumbers using NSDataDetector [NSDataDetector with NSTextCheckingTypeLink detects URL and PhoneNumbers!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965844/nsdatadetector-with-nstextcheckingtypelink-detects-url-and-phonenumbers)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `NSDataDetector` class.