# Finding a url in NSString

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, url, nsstring

How can I search a `NSString` for a url in Xcode iOS? 
For instance, If scan it for

> HTTP://

and detect where the end of that url is and return the url string.

```
     NSSearchFieldCell Class Reference
```

is only available on Mac development.

Comment: NSRange option is available in iPhone like [temp1 rangeOfString:@"http"]

Comment: Update: You guys rock! I found a great code here too- (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965844/nsdatadetector-with-nstextcheckingtypelink-detects-url-and-phonenumbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this link I think it should be work [NSDataDetector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html)