# Can NSDataDetector be made to detect URLs but not email addresses?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdatadetector

I've implemented `NSDataDetector` to detect URLs, but it includes email addresses as well. Is there an easy way to make it not detect emails, but all other URLs?

Comment: See Dave DeLong's answer to this stack overflow question: [NSDataDetector with NSTextCheckingTypeLink detects URL and PhoneNumbers!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965844/nsdatadetector-with-nstextcheckingtypelink-detects-url-and-phonenumbers). You want to pull out all the URLs and then filter on the URL scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, email addresses are not URLs. `mailto:someone@some.where.com` is a URL which *contains* an email address. So, to answer your question: Check whether your URL begins with `mailto:`. If it does, ignore it. If for some reason you're picking up email addresses as URLs, you probably have some parsing bug...

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/1593077) about regular expressions for URLs.

Comment: Data detectors were created specifically to detect things like emial addresses that aren't in URL form.

Comment: @jshier: I'm not much of an iOS developer, but [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says they're used for URLs also.